# Object not showing up anymore, I don't know why

Tags: java, arraylist

I had the enemy as a array[] but I recently changed it to an arrayList[] but for some reason nothing shows up anymore, any ideas?

```
ArrayList<Character> enemy = new ArrayList<Character>(20);
Character enty;

String[] eny = {"Eny_.png" , "eny2.png", "eny3.png"};   

    for (int i = 0; i < enemy.size(); i ++) {
        int ranX = 700 + (int)(Math.random() * 2000);
        int ranY = 100 + (int)(Math.random() * 360);
        int randE = (int)(Math.random() * 2);

        enty = new Character(ranX, ranY,0,0,100,25);
        enty.setImage(eny[randE]);
        enemy.add(i, enty);
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < enemy.size(); i ++) {
        int ranSpeed = -1 + (int)(Math.random() * -2);
        System.out.println(ranSpeed);
        enemy.get(i).setVelX(ranSpeed);
        enemy.get(i).getVelX();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the i stand for in `enemy.add(i,enty)`?

Comment: @John `i` is the loop index in that case.

Comment: Okay @azurefrog I clarified some more at the top.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you *really* shouldn't name your classes the same as core classes.  Anyone seeing `Character` is going to think `java.lang.Character` and be confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the 20 in

```
ArrayList<Character> enemy = new ArrayList<Character>(20)
```

Is the initial *capacity*, not the initial size.  So,

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemy.size(); i ++) {
```

is not doing anything because `enemy.size()` is zero.

Comment: Thank you and @Hoopje, it works now!

Answer (score 4):

The constructor `new ArrayList<Character>(20)` does not create an `ArrayList` of size 20, it constructs an empty `ArrayList` with an initial capacity of 20. So, in your first loop, `enemy.size()` equals 0.

If you want to add 20 enemies, just use the constant 20 in your loop.